# Searching through objects inside nested documents provides unexpected output

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-7, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I am getting unexpected result from Elasticsearch while searching though object property which are inside nested property. I am using elasticsearch-dsl python library for creating document and querying. Is this bug or I am missing something in querying and mapping parts? Below are the elasticsearch json mapping, query, unexpected result and expected result

Mapping:

```
{
  "deal_acls": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
      "created_at": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "created_by": {
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "status": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "lowercase"
          }
        }
      },
      "permission": {
        "properties": {
          "CRM": {
            "properties": {
              "description": {
                "properties": {
                  "created_by": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "normalizer": "lowercase"
                  },
                  "object": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "normalizer": "lowercase"
                  },
                  "object_id": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "normalizer": "lowercase"
                  },
                  "timestamp": {
                    "type": "date"
                  }
                }
              },
              "permission": {
                "properties": {
                  "delete": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  },
                  "edit": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  },
                  "manage": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "read": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  },
                  "write": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "deal": {
            "properties": {
              "description": {
                "properties": {
                  "created_by": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "normalizer": "lowercase"
                  },
                  "object": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "normalizer": "lowercase"
                  },
                  "object_id": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "normalizer": "lowercase"
                  },
                  "timestamp": {
                    "type": "date"
                  }
                }
              },
              "permission": {
                "properties": {
                  "delete": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  },
                  "edit": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  },
                  "manage": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "read": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  },
                  "write": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "document": {
            "properties": {
              "description": {
                "properties": {
                  "created_by": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "normalizer": "lowercase"
                  },
                  "object": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "normalizer": "lowercase"
                  },
                  "object_id": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "normalizer": "lowercase"
                  },
                  "timestamp": {
                    "type": "date"
                  }
                }
              },
              "permission": {
                "properties": {
                  "delete": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  },
                  "edit": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  },
                  "manage": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "read": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  },
                  "write": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "external_deal_team": {
            "properties": {
              "description": {
                "properties": {
                  "created_by": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "normalizer": "lowercase"
                  },
                  "object": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "normalizer": "lowercase"
                  },
                  "object_id": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "normalizer": "lowercase"
                  },
                  "timestamp": {
                    "type": "date"
                  }
                }
              },
              "permission": {
                "properties": {
                  "delete": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  },
                  "edit": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  },
                  "manage": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "read": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  },
                  "write": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "internal_deal_team": {
            "properties": {
              "description": {
                "properties": {
                  "created_by": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "normalizer": "lowercase"
                  },
                  "object": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "normalizer": "lowercase"
                  },
                  "object_id": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "normalizer": "lowercase"
                  },
                  "timestamp": {
                    "type": "date"
                  }
                }
              },
              "permission": {
                "properties": {
                  "delete": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  },
                  "edit": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  },
                  "manage": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "read": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  },
                  "write": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "status": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "lowercase"
      },
      "updated_at": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "updated_by": {
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "status": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "lowercase"
          }
        }
      },
      "user": {
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "status": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "lowercase"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "deal_acls",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "deal_acls.permission.deal.permission.read": 1
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "deal_acls",
            "query": {
              "terms": {
                "deal_acls.user.id": [
                  "5f7cea05-6562-4bdd-8448-19cfbe11783a"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Unexpected result: ***Since the deal permission of user with id=5f7cea05-6562-4bdd-8448-19cfbe11783a is 0, it should be returning empty hits.***

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 2,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "dev.crecentric.dealvault.deals",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "a928838d-3422-41db-b40e-28f5c793f806",
        "_score": 2,
        "_source": {
          "id": "a928838d-3422-41db-b40e-28f5c793f806",
          "deal_acls": [
            {
              "user": {
                "id": "5f7cea05-6562-4bdd-8448-19cfbe11783a",
                "name": "testerrrrs testesssss",
                "status": "active"
              },
              "permission": {
                "deal": {
                  "permission": {
                    "edit": 0,
                    "read": 0,
                    "write": 0,
                    "delete": 0,
                    "manage": 0
                  },
                  "description": {
                    "object": "workspace",
                    "object_id": "fbc840b1-8727-4945-a070-fa1c105f9550",
                    "timestamp": "2022-02-10T05:46:05.140867+00:00",
                    "created_by": "d78411e5-6645-4b95-a98c-db6db8748580"
                  }
                },
                "external_deal_team": {
                  "permission": {
                    "edit": 0,
                    "read": 1,
                    "write": 1,
                    "delete": 0,
                    "manage": 0
                  },
                  "description": {
                    "object": "workspace",
                    "object_id": "fbc840b1-8727-4945-a070-fa1c105f9550",
                    "timestamp": "2022-02-10T05:46:05.140902+00:00",
                    "created_by": "d78411e5-6645-4b95-a98c-db6db8748580"
                  }
                },
                "internal_deal_team": {
                  "permission": {
                    "edit": 0,
                    "read": 1,
                    "write": 1,
                    "delete": 0,
                    "manage": 0
                  },
                  "description": {
                    "object": "workspace",
                    "object_id": "fbc840b1-8727-4945-a070-fa1c105f9550",
                    "timestamp": "2022-02-10T05:46:05.140910+00:00",
                    "created_by": "d78411e5-6645-4b95-a98c-db6db8748580"
                  }
                }
              },
              "status": "active",
              "created_at": "2022-02-10T05:40:15.727598+05:45",
              "updated_at": "2022-02-10T05:46:05.177076+05:45"
            },
            {
              "user": {
                "id": "d78411e5-6645-4b95-a98c-db6db8748580",
                "name": "Ramesh Pradhan",
                "status": "active"
              },
              "permission": {
                "CRM": {
                  "permission": {
                    "edit": 1,
                    "read": 1,
                    "write": 1,
                    "delete": 1,
                    "manage": 1
                  },
                  "description": {
                    "object": "owner",
                    "object_id": "d78411e5-6645-4b95-a98c-db6db8748580",
                    "timestamp": "2022-02-10T05:35:41.453881+00:00",
                    "created_by": "d78411e5-6645-4b95-a98c-db6db8748580"
                  }
                },
                "deal": {
                  "permission": {
                    "edit": 1,
                    "read": 1,
                    "write": 1,
                    "delete": 1,
                    "manage": 1
                  },
                  "description": {
                    "object": "owner",
                    "object_id": "d78411e5-6645-4b95-a98c-db6db8748580",
                    "timestamp": "2022-02-10T05:35:41.453881+00:00",
                    "created_by": "d78411e5-6645-4b95-a98c-db6db8748580"
                  }
                },
                "document": {
                  "permission": {
                    "edit": 1,
                    "read": 1,
                    "write": 1,
                    "delete": 1,
                    "manage": 1
                  },
                  "description": {
                    "object": "owner",
                    "object_id": "d78411e5-6645-4b95-a98c-db6db8748580",
                    "timestamp": "2022-02-10T05:35:41.453881+00:00",
                    "created_by": "d78411e5-6645-4b95-a98c-db6db8748580"
                  }
                },
                "external_deal_team": {
                  "permission": {
                    "edit": 1,
                    "read": 1,
                    "write": 1,
                    "delete": 1,
                    "manage": 1
                  },
                  "description": {
                    "object": "owner",
                    "object_id": "d78411e5-6645-4b95-a98c-db6db8748580",
                    "timestamp": "2022-02-10T05:35:41.453881+00:00",
                    "created_by": "d78411e5-6645-4b95-a98c-db6db8748580"
                  }
                },
                "internal_deal_team": {
                  "permission": {
                    "edit": 1,
                    "read": 1,
                    "write": 1,
                    "delete": 1,
                    "manage": 1
                  },
                  "description": {
                    "object": "owner",
                    "object_id": "d78411e5-6645-4b95-a98c-db6db8748580",
                    "timestamp": "2022-02-10T05:35:41.453881+00:00",
                    "created_by": "d78411e5-6645-4b95-a98c-db6db8748580"
                  }
                }
              },
              "status": "active",
              "created_at": "2022-02-10T05:35:41.453913+05:45",
              "updated_at": "2022-02-10T05:35:41.462956+05:45"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Expected result:

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 2,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using two nested queries: so the result is a document which contains `"deal_acls.permission.deal.permission.read": 1` and `"deal_acls.user.id": ["5f7cea05-6562-4bdd-8448-19cfbe11783a"]`, but not necessary in the same subobject of the nested field. Try using a [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) inside a single nested query:

```
{ 
"query": { 
    "nested": {
        "path": "deal_acls",
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    { "match": { "deal_acls.user.id": "5f7cea05-6562-4bdd-8448-19cfbe11783a" }},
                    { "match": { "deal_acls.permission.deal.permission.read":  1 }} 
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Elasticsearch 7.x doesn't support this syntax. We cannot use terms for multiple fields.

Comment: @RameshPradhan true, you have to use bool-match, will correct the answer now

Answer (score 0):

In case if someone is searching for answer, I have fixed this using this query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "deal_acls",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "deal_acls.permission.deal.permission.read": 1
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "deal_acls.user.id": [
                  "5f7cea05-6562-4bdd-8448-19cfbe11783a"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```